# Timeout in connection between Cloud SQL and App Engine

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

My java web app, which could successfully connect to my Postgresql database hosted on Google cloud sql, was deployed to Google App Engine. Now, everytime it tries to access the very same database, I get a Timeout error. Do I need to configure something for them to communicate properly ? Both the Web Application and the Database are located in the same project, so I just assumed they were allowed to communicate to one another

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at weightwatchers2019.UsuarioDAO.autenticar(UsuarioDAO.java:79)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue could it be caused by :

If there is a temporary problem with the server

All prepared statements and resultsets, check the max_connections.

Idle connections timing out of the NAT connection tables of NAT

The firewall is blocking the response from the server.

Another reason is that the host name is incorrect.

Are you sure that your database is running on port 8080.

This could also mean there is a (temporary) problem with the server (or some router along the way). You can try a traceroute to determine whether or not this is true.

Check:
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://19x.16x.1x.13x/MxxGS","username", "password");

Confirm your jdbc (jar) for postgres.

Try exceptions, or a pool connection for the DB.